# Xbee3 - Calculation of trigonometric values without math module

Tags: math, trigonometry, xbee, micropython

I'm using MicroPython on an Xbee3-24 and it has no `math` module internally. I need to calculate *sin*, *cos* and *arctan* values.

How can I use trigonometric functions without using the `math` module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use power series to approximate [trigonometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Power_series_expansion) and [inverse trigonometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Infinite_series) (and most other functions, for that matter).

For example, you could define a function that approximately calculates *sin(x)* as:

```
def approx_sin(x):
    return x - (pow(x, 3)/6) + (pow(x, 5)/120) - (pow(x, 7)/5040)
```

That has a maximum error of 0.0752 from the true value in the range *-pi <= x <= pi* (on desktop Python 3.6). If you need better accuracy, add more terms - and if you need to handle *x* outside that range, bring it in to that range first.